# Do images w/ display:none still make an HTTP request?

Tags: html, css, performance, image, http

In stylesheet:

```css
#sj {display: none}
```

In HTML:

```
<img id="sj" src="scarlett-johansson.jpg" width="640" height="360" alt="scarlett johansson" />
```

Does an HTTP request for the image happen or not?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, they still cause an HTTP request. Example: http://jsfiddle.net/RzFG2/

Answer (score 7):

There is a way to prevent an HTTP request when using `display:none`. You need to make the image a `background-image` in CSS and set the parent element to `display:none`.

HTML:

```
<div id="test3">
    <div></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```css
#test3 div {
    background-image:url('images/test3.png');
    width:200px;
    height:75px;
}
@media all and (max-width: 600px) {
    #test3 {
        display:none;
    }
}
```

Here is a [link](http://timkadlec.com/2012/04/media-query-asset-downloading-results/) where you can read about all sorts of tests on this issue.

Comment: using image in background-image css property without giving parent div display:none; makes any request?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the request still goes out but the image is not displayed.

Answer (score 1):

You can test if there was a request in browser console <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>J</kbd> and in **Network** section filter **Img** elements and see if they are loaded upon refresh.

Well, this is how You can test it but I am here because of that I was to lazy to check this by myself and it was faster to look for it on stackoverflow :)